# How to reference two structs from each other

Tags: c

I have two structs which need to contain pointers to each other.  But when I try to define them as below, I get a warning.

I need to know if I need to write a declaration before using one struct in another.

```
typedef struct
{
    char *nameBook;
    char *auother;
    ppl*p;
}book;

typedef struct
{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastname;
    int id;
    book **books;
    int num_of_your_books;
}ppl;
```

Comment: Please edit the question if your comment contradicts.

Comment: What is the warning you receive?

Comment: 1) the waring is certainly not about "calling". C is no OOP language, so a `struct` cannot call another. Please learn [ask] and provide all and correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a forward declaration of one of the structs to reference the other, and you'll need to give the structs themselves names so they can be referenced without the typedef:

```
struct ppl;

typedef struct book
{
    char *nameBook;
    char *auother;
    struct ppl *p;
}book;

typedef struct ppl
{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastname;
    int id;
    struct book **books;
    int num_of_your_books;
}ppl;
```

Comment: and if not? can i add a declaration that it will work?

Comment: Can you give the struct and the struct-typedef the same name?

Comment: @n.levin I edited just before you commented.

Comment: @Mijago structs and typedefs have different namespaces in C, so having the same name is not an issue.

Comment: @n.levin Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.